# How to speak ‘in 1908’？

Tags: word-usage

In + year, such as 1908.  How to speak it？

In **nineteen and eight** or in **nineteen eight**？

Which is correct？

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is actually **nineteen oh eight**.

(**Nineteen hundred and eight** is also correct but is very rarely heard now.)